# Move onBeforeAction hook in Meteor iron-router to different file

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I use the following function as a helper for my `onBeforeAction` hook:

```
var gameFilter = function () {
    this.subscribe('singleGame', this.params.slug);
    var game = this.data();
    if (game) {
        if (game.multiplayer) {
            this.redirect('multiPlayerPage', {slug: this.params.slug});
        } else {
            this.subscribe('singlePlayerPage', this.params.slug);
        }
    } else {
        this.render(this.notFoundTemplate);
    }
    this.next();
};
```

I use it like this in my route:

```
onBeforeAction: [gameFilter, playerFilter]
```

Now this works fantastic. However, I want to move all filters to a different file. So I created a new file in my `lib` directory and put the following code in:

```
gameFilter = function () {
    this.subscribe('singleGame', this.params.slug);
    var game = this.data();
    if (game) {
        if (game.multiplayer) {
            this.redirect('multiPlayerPage', {slug: this.params.slug});
        } else {
            this.subscribe('singlePlayerPage', this.params.slug);
        }
    } else {
        this.render(this.notFoundTemplate);
    }
    this.next();
};
```

The problem is, that I get a ReferenceError, saying that `gameFilter` is not defined. I think this issue is caused by Meteor's file load order. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: You could export it to some local package, files are added in the order you write them in package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue with Meteor. The Workaround was to change the name of the File or folder to number so that it is loaded first.  it my case it was a file called `media.js` and i changed to `1_media.js` and it worked